# Windows Explorer - Diff two files from the context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, diff

Is there any way to diff two selected files from the context menu in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like you need [**diff-ext**](http://diff-ext.sourceforge.net/)!

> This shell extension (diff-ext) makes
>   it possible to launch file comparison
>   tool for 2 or 3 files (depending on
>   the tool) in the same directory or
>   "save" a file(s) for later comparison.
>   It acts as external most recent used
>   (MRU) file list for the comparison
>   tool.

I'm using it with [**KDiff3**](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), but there are a number of other diff tools on the page it can be used with.

[image]

Comment: You're more than welcome!

Comment: Did not work well on my windows 7. I have configured it with the path to diff.exe and all I get is something blinking in front of my eyes. Is this application diff aware at all?

Comment: Works OK on Win7 but I'm using Meld as my diff tool.

Comment: KDiff3 already has a context menu extension integrated now (`Kdiff3` => `Compare`), so if you just need something quick & easy, that might be enough.

Comment: I may have to give this a go, but I use exclusively gvim, so not sure how well that will turn out

Answer (score 11):

Here's my solution to add a Right Click context menu entry to run a custom command (like calling Meld) and diff two files.

**Background**
Simple context menu entries can be be easily added in Windows register (regedit): manually or by creating a .reg file (see example below).

The problem is that the command will be run for each file you select.
There are three solutions to solve this:

1. Use Shell extensions (complicated)
2. Make sure your application catch the different calls (complicated)
3. Use `singleinstance.exe` from [context-menu-handler](https://github.com/zenden2k/context-menu-launcher) (simple). This program does option 2 for you. It collects arguments from the different time it is called and then pass these to the command you want. A time-out option is available to help gather calls to be collected. Follow the link for more info.

**Step 1** Download singleinstance.exe from [context-menu-handler](https://github.com/zenden2k/context-menu-launcher) (and thank the author, to whom I'm not related)

**Step 2 (for file and folder comparison)**: Create a file with extension ".reg" with the following content (example for Meld with an Icon):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\DiffIt_Files]
@="Diff it!"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\Meld.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\DiffIt_Files\command]
@="\"c:\\Bin\\singleinstance.exe\" \"%1\" \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\Meld.exe\" $files --si-timeout 400"
   
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\DiffIt_Folders] 
@="Diff It!" 
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\Meld.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\DiffIt_Folders\command]    
@="\"c:\\Bin\\singleinstance.exe\" \"%1\" \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\Meld.exe\" $files --si-timeout 400"
```

The reg file create a context menu entry labelled "Diff It!" for all files (`*`) and for Folders (`Folder`). The lines containing the `Icon` can be removed if you don't want an icon.

Adapt the path of the program `singleinstance.exe` and the command run (here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe`. Note the escaping of the backspaces and the quotes

**Step 3** Run the `.reg` file. Double clicking on it might work if you are admin. Otherwise open an admin command prompt in your folder (in explorer: File>Open Command> Open Command as admin. or `Alt-F-M-A`).  Simply Type the name of the `.reg` file to add it to the registry.

**That's it.**

**(uninstall)** You can either delete the keys manually in the registry or create a `.reg` file with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\DiffIt_Files]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\DiffIt_Folders]
```

**Alternative** Use a software to add-edit-remove context menu entries like ContextEdit (but can't add icon easily). In this case you don't need to escape the slashes and the quotes so the command would look like this:

```
"c:\Bin\singleinstance.exe "%1" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe" $files --si-timeout 400
```

Comment: Worked for me...

Comment: Overall, I like this implementation.  However, sadly, it creates a new instance of Meld each time the context menu is used.  Any tips for getting it to use the existing instance?  I assume that was the intention of `singleinstance.exe`.  Maybe it's not compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: Fix for the icon to show up: "Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\Meld.exe"

Answer (score 3):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) and [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) can also do this if you enable *Shell Integration* during the installation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a batch file with the custom command, then add a shortcut to it in `shell:sendto`. As a bonus, this avoids changing the registry too.

Inspired by [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45714611/2983132), for example:

1a. Create a new file with:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal
    start "Compare files" /B /MIN "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /diff %2 %1 First:'%2' Second:'%1'
```

1b. Change the [start command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649634/how-do-i-run-a-bat-file-in-the-background-from-another-bat-file/8351295#8351295), e.g. change the path to your compare tool and subsequent command line arguments as appropriate.

2. Save the batch file to a permanent directory, e.g. `C:\Users\You\Compare With My Tool.cmd`.
3. Create a shortcut to your `Compare With My Tool.cmd` file inside `shell:sendto`. The shortcut's name is what you will see on the Send To context menu. The icon that appears in the shell is the icon of the shortcut and you can change this using the file properties menu.
4. Select the two files to compare, right-click, and select Send To > Compare With My Tool (or whatever you named your shortcut)

Comment: You don't need to create a batch file, just use the Meld shortcut. See https://superuser.com/a/1567468/478867. This worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you. Very nice, easy and flexible way.